# How can I send firebase notification to my app users, if API get updated?

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter, function, dart

I am using flutter and firebase to develop my app. But here is the problem I faced. I am using twitter API to fetch some news to users. But I don't know how can I send notifications to user if twitter API gets updated each time??